# Looping through the elements of 2d ArrayList and outputting its coordinates

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to output the coordinates (`rows` and `cols` numbers) from the `Arraylist` but getting this error - the loop does not read after the first element of a row!. Please do not pay attentiong to the variable `this.element` which is passed to the constructor. All I care about is only ouputting the rows and cols in correct form like in the following:

```
[[(0,1,a)], [(0,2,a)], [(0,3,a)], [(1,0,a)], [(1,1,a)], [(1,2,a)]]...
```

but my code gives me this:

```
[[(0,0,a)], [(1,0,a)], [(2,0,a)], [(3,0,a)], [(4,0,a)], [(5,0,a)]]
```

i.e. it simply does not read after the first element of a row. Please could smb help me with that? What did I do wrong? The problem rises when I call the method `getLongestSequence();`

Answer (score 1):

You pass this

```
String[][] myString = {{"A B C"}, {"A A A"}, {"B A C"}, {"B E C"}, ...
```

which looks quite single dimensional to me, to this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
    values.add(x[i][j]);
}
```

but since every x[i] has only length 1 (a single string), only one element is added to each row.

As far as I know, you can't index strings with brackets in Java.

Maybe you want to pass

```
String[][] myString = {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"A", "A", "A"}, {"B", "A", "C"}, ...
```

Comment: That's what I figured out minutes ago :). Thanks though!